# Bootstrap modal issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the twitter bootstrap in my latest project. It all works fine, except for one of the pages.

Clicking on the link brings up a modal, which I can close using the close button or the close icon on the top right corner of the modal.

However is I close the modal using the close button and then try to open it again (or any other link for that matter) the close button is disabled and I can only close the modal using the top right icon.

Below is a link to jsfiddle with a copy of my code where you can see the results live.

There is only one modal to which the data will be passed on by the link, however this is not implemented yet.

```
<h3>Select a role to edit it.</h3>
<div style="width:auto">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleEditModal">(920)Active Directory Management</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleEditModal">(904)Cisco Router - Administration </a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleEditModal">(914)Cisco Router - Installation</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleEditModal">(918)Development - Analysis</a></li><li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleEditModal">(908)Development - Project Management</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roleEditModal">(936)Fire Wall - Administration</a></li>
</ul>
</div>        
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal" id="roleEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="roleEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModal">Edit role:</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btn_roleEditClose" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzfbyu6t/

Could someone take a look at it and let me know where is my problem.
Thank

Answer (score 1):

The javascript you added is causing the problem.

```
    $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    if (! $(this).hasClass("disabled"))
        {
            $(".disabled").removeClass("disabled").attr("rel", null);

            $(this).addClass("disabled").attr("rel", "tooltip");
        }
    });
```

if you comment out this works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/dzfbyu6t/1/